# How to start pm2 process with DEBUG option

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have an express app that I start in terminal with following command to enable debug logs in it:

```
DEBUG=custom:* npm start (on Ubuntu)
SET DEBUG=custom:* & npm start (on Windows)
```

On production server, I start app with PM2 using following command:

```
pm2 start bin/www -i 0
```

But this does not enable the `debug` logs in my code, so the debug statements are not added to the logs, only `console.error()` are added to the log files. How can I pass the `DEBUG=custom:*` option while starting my app with PM2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `DEBUG='custom:*' pm2 start bin/www -i 0`

If you are restarting an existing process add the --update-env flag:

`DEBUG='custom:*' pm2 restart bin/www -i 0 --update-env`

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work. But the `debug` logs are going to `www-error-0.log` file not the `www-out-0.log` file. I was expecting these debug logs to go to output log file not error log file. Is that expected?

Comment: Are you using winston for logging? This is the default behavior for it. You can use `stderrLevels` to define which logs go to err and which out. More here: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#console-transport

Comment: I'm using default `debug` module. Anyway, your solution solved my problem :). Thanks a lot Mikko :)

Comment: Well, yes of course it's debug, I wasn't thinking.. :) Anyway it seems that the it too can also be configured similarly as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug#output-streams

Answer (score 3):

Mikko was correct but if you add that to package.json scripts, it won't work!

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "DEBUG='custom:*' pm2 start bin/www -i 0",
    ...
  },
```

Because DEBUG='custom:*' is given to pm2 process NOT your process. So in this case you have to use an ecosystem file and add DEBUG setting in ecosystem file, e.g.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js",
    ...
  },

//in ecosystem.config.js add this
env: {
    NODE_ENV: 'development',
    DEBUG: 'custom:*'
},
```